# The document “podfile” could not be opened in CococaPods client

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile, cocoapods-app

Use CococaPods client to open the `podfile` meet the error below:

> The document “podfile” could not be opened

I also token pictures to show detail:

[image]

You see, I can not open the podfile and Podfile.lock

With the error:

[image]

So, how to open the podfile with CocoaPods client?

---

**Edit -1**

My CocoaPods client is download from here: [CocoaPods client](https://cocoapods.org/app), and its version is `v-1.1.1`.

The download link is:https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods-app/releases/download/1.1.1/CocoaPods.app-1.1.1.tar.bz2/

Comment: Go to your project folder from Terminal, Type 'vim Podfile', it opens Podfile in cmd mode, type 'i' and start editing your file Or else open file with TextEdit Mac App.

Comment: @Imad Ali, I know how to use vim to open `Podfile`, I just want to use CocoaPods client to open it.

Comment: Could you please share Cocoapods client? I generally use the vim Podfile Or else TextEdit.

Comment: @Imad Ali, see my `Edit -1`.

Comment: Yeah I can see your edit, I'm asking the URL for the Cocoapods Client for download?